# Get the next number in a list of numbers using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of numbers as below:

```
var mylist = new List<double> {1, 5, 8, 10, 12};
```

How can I get the number after a specific number. I want an `LINQ` expression that receives for example `8` and gives me `10`;

Comment: What should be the answer if I ask for number after 12?

Comment: @PetarRepac The number after 12 doesn't matter. I'll check it in a condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
double result = mylist.SkipWhile(n => n != 8).Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: he has a list of doubles, so I would recommend using `Math.Abs(n - 8) > 0.00001` in `Where` clause

Comment: If you run this and ask for number after 12 you'll get an exception.

Comment: @PetarRepac Yes, it would generate exception. But getting `FirstOrDefault()` will return `0`, which is incorrect too.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Yes, it makes sense for non-integer doubles, but OP can make that change by himself.

Answer (score 2):

This should also work if you do not have duplicate numbers.

```
int index = mylist.IndexOf(8);

if (index != -1)
{
   double result = index == mylist.Count - 1 ? mylist[index] : mylist[index + 1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Selman, does this have any performance advantage to the answer given by Ulugbek?

Comment: I can't say there will be a significant difference,but ofcourse the best way to make sure is measuring. otherwise use whichever you find more readable

Comment: AFAIK no performance advantage, if you give 12 as input you'll get 12 back.

Comment: I find this answer more intuitive but I had asked for a LINQ answer in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This should [work](http://ideone.com/L8hmo0),

```
var mylist = new List<double> { 1, 5, 8, 10, 12 };
double p = 8;

var result = mylist.Where(x => x > p).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1.  This almost takes all the fun out of solving the problem in LINQ.

Comment: OP never said list is ordered.